# How to start mimosa coffeescript project on command line

Tags: node.js, requirejs, mimosa

I used mimosa to generate an express app, and work with it using mimosa watch --server.  Everything is great.

There is a server.coffee file, autogenerated by mimosa and requirejs compliant, that contains the line
exports.startServer = function(config) {  ... }

How do I start that through the command line?  I try coffee server.coffee, sometimes with an -r.

Thanks!

OMGoodness, forgot to mention I am on Windows.  Everything else has worked the same as any examples I find on the internet (NPM wasn't installing well 6 months ago, but things are really good lately).

Node v 0.8.14  coffee 1.4.0  mimosa 0.6.1

Mimosa says it runs startServer from server.coffee. What is the equivalent from a command line considering requirejs format of server.coffee?

Comment: "I try `coffee server.coffee`" What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: It just returns.  Cofffe -r server.coffee does this:

Comment: module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'server.coffee'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at loadRequires (C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:242:7)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:64:7)
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: (C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee:7:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mimosa author here.  Sorry I didn't notice this sooner!  You are always welcome to come to the Google Group to ask questions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mimosajs That'll get noticed right away!

`coffee server.coffee` isn't what you should be executing.

Once you've run `mimosa new`, the project you are delivered it started by executing `mimosa watch -s`.  That starts the watching of the file system, builds all the files, and then starts the server by calling the `startServer` method of your server file.

Comment: David,Thanks for your great work.  I do what you suggest for dev.  I'm more asking about deployment.  I finally found your deploy addon library which is working fine.  https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-web-package.  I was the guy with problems crossing win/unix configurations, whom you tried to help Christmas eve or something!  This reminds me I need to discover what you asked me then, rather than continuing the kludge I use.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, the web-package module was made just to handle the "I want to deploy this app, now what?" question.  Because `server.coffee` needs to export a hook for Mimosa to call into, it means the server is started via a function call rather than just being required in.  So when you just type `coffee server.coffee` you aren't calling that function.  All web-package does is give you an additional piece of code that imports your server and calls that function.  I was definitely keen to provide some means to use a fully built Mimosa app without using Mimosa.  Glad it is working for you!!